# Book to prepare for Evans’ PDE’s

Tags: reference-request

I’m a graduate student, and I’m looking to start studying PDE’s at the level of Evans’ *Partial Differential Equations* next semester after having completed the measure theory course this semester. During the fall break, I would like to revise on basic/undergrad PDE’s and/or any other pre-requisite material for Evans’ textbook? Any suggestions for textbooks that meet this criterion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually used this textbook during my graduate studies. From my own experience, there is no official solution manual for the textbook and you'll likely need to Google the solutions for the problems individually .